# Business logic validation with Entity Framework and IDataErrorInfo

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, validation, mvvm, idataerrorinfo

I'm working on a project using WPF and MVVM with Entity Framework 4.3, and I would like to know how can I perform business logic validation implementing the IDataErrorInfo interface.

All of my models (POCO classes) are implementing it in order to perform raw validations, like maxlength, non-negative numbers, and so on...

But what about bussiness logic validation, such as to prevent duplicate records?

Imagine I have a textbox for a material "reference", which must be unique, defined liked this:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Material.Reference, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=true, 
                                 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

The model will successfully validate the reference's length, but if there's already a material in my viewmodel's materials observablecollection, how should I notify the user of this fact from my ViewModel, yet taking advantage of the IDataErrorInfo messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this in the past by exposing a validation delegate from my models that my ViewModels can hook into for additional business logic validation

The end result ends up looking like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    // Keeping these generic to reduce code here, but they
    // should be full properties with PropertyChange notification
    public ObservableCollection<MyModel> MyCollection { get; set; }
    public MyModel SelectedModel { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyCollection = DAL.GetAllModels();

        // Add the validation delegate to each object
        foreach(var model in MyCollection)
            model.AddValidationErrorDelegate(ValidateModel);
    }

    // Validation Delegate to verify the object's name is unique
    private string ValidateObject(object sender, string propertyName)
    {
        if (propertyName == "Name")
        {
            var obj = (MyModel)sender;
            var existingCount = MyCollection.Count(p => 
                p.Name == obj.Name && p.Id != obj.Id);

            if (existingCount > 0)
                return "This name has already been taken";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Most of my models inherit from a generic base class, which includes this validation delegate. Here's the relevant code from that base class, taken from my blog article on [Validating Business Rules in MVVM](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/01/22/validating-business-rules-in-mvvm/)

```
#region IDataErrorInfo & Validation Members

/// <summary>
/// List of Property Names that should be validated.
/// Usually populated by the Model's Constructor
/// </summary>
protected List<string> ValidatedProperties = new List<string>();

#region Validation Delegate

public delegate string ValidationErrorDelegate(
    object sender, string propertyName);

private List<ValidationErrorDelegate> _validationDelegates = new List<ValidationErrorDelegate>();

public void AddValidationErrorDelegate(
    ValidationErrorDelegate func)
{
    _validationDelegates.Add(func);
}

#endregion // Validation Delegate

#region IDataErrorInfo for binding errors

string IDataErrorInfo.Error { get { return null; } }

string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
{
    get { return this.GetValidationError(propertyName); }
}

public string GetValidationError(string propertyName)
{
    // Check to see if this property has any validation
    if (ValidatedProperties.IndexOf(propertyName) >= 0)
    {
        string s = null;

        foreach (var func in _validationDelegates)
        {
            s = func(this, propertyName);
            if (s != null)
                return s;
        }
    }

    return s;
}

#endregion // IDataErrorInfo for binding errors

#region IsValid Property

public bool IsValid
{
    get
    {
        return (GetValidationError() == null);
    }
}

public string GetValidationError()
{
    string error = null;

    if (ValidatedProperties != null)
    {
        foreach (string s in ValidatedProperties)
        {
            error = GetValidationError(s);
            if (error != null)
                return error;
        }
    }

    return error;
}

#endregion // IsValid Property

#endregion // IDataErrorInfo & Validation Members
```

This allows me to keep the basic data validation in my Models, and my ViewModels can attach any customized business logic validation they want to the Model as well.

Comment: Thanks, I already left the office but tomorrow I'll give this a try.

Comment: It works great! Just to let you know, your code contains tiny errors like: List types are not defined, s is not defined and there's a >= operator missing in ValidatedProperties.IndexOf(propertyName)  0.

Comment: @EduardoBrites Thanks, I've had issues with wordpress removing some special characters when I copy code to it, so I'll be sure and get that fixed this weekend :)

Comment: Just one more thing, I have a trigger in my view binding to the IsValid property that currently's not working. How can I force this trigger to evaluate whenever the object stop being valid?

Comment: @EduardoBrites Its hard to tell without seeing the code, but verify the property changed notification is getting raised for the `IsValid` property whenever the value changes. If it's successfully getting raised, then the problem might be with the trigger. If not, then simply raise the property changed event for `IsValid` whenever the validation runs.

Comment: I just don't know where to raise the IsValid property changed event. The IsValid property is being called whenever a control content changes, do I have to put NotifyPropertyChanged("IsValid") in every viewmodel's property set accessor? Sorry if I'm bugging you...

Comment: @EduardoBrites It's fine, although perhaps you can post a new question with your code in it? You may just have to call `RaisePropertyChanged("IsValid")` in the `GetValidationError()` method before it returns a value

Comment: I posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651446/where-to-raise-notifypropertychanged

Comment: @Rachel a question regarding this: you said you placed this in the Models base class, you'd create a partial class in the Models folder for this? If I regenerate my Models classes from my edmx, wouldn't my inheritance to this validationbase be gone?

Comment: @chickenricekid Its been a while so I can't remember for sure, but I thought there was a way to specify a base class for your emdx models.