# Where to raise NotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I just implemented my business logic validation according to Rachel Lim's [blog](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/01/22/validating-business-rules-in-mvvm/).
Everything was running great until I decided to put a trigger in my view bound to the **IsValid** property like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding EdgedBoards}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelEdgedBoard, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"> 
                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
                            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsValid}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ListBox>
```

The problem is that when the bound item has an error (SelEdgedBoard.IsValid == false) the trigger is not notified to reevaluate and the item keeps its focusable property to true.

I've already tried to put a NotifyPropertyChanged("IsValid") before the GetValidationError() returns its value, but this way I get a stackoverflow exception:

```
#region IsValid Property

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(GetValidationError());
        }
    }

    public string GetValidationError()
    {
        string error = null;

        if (ValidatedProperties != null)
        {
            foreach (string s in ValidatedProperties)
            {
                error = GetValidationError(s);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(error))
                {
                    break; 
                }
            }
        }

        NotifyPropertyChanged("IsValid");
        return error;
    }

    #endregion
```

Comment: What sort of test are you using to make the object invalid? And does it work if you switch your trigger to be based on `Validation.HasError` instead? `<Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">`

Comment: I know the object it's invalid, I can see that either in the UI or in the code. Changing the Xaml to <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True"> does not work either...

Comment: Does it work if you change a different property in the trigger, such as background color? I wonder if it has something to do with the Focusable property

Comment: I just tried that and the background is not updated also...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it causes a stack overflow. When you do:

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("IsValid")
```

You force the WPF infrastructure to reevaluate the value of IsValid. It does this by calling the IsValid getter, which, in turn, calls GetValidationError again!

There are several ways you can handle this. I would probably create a private member variable to hold the last value of IsValid and then compare the current value to the old value before calling NotifyPropertyChanged.

Another way might be to only call NotifyPropertyChanged("IsValid") when one of your validated properties changes (so in the setter of each of those properties) as this is what *might* cause a change in IsValid.

Comment: About your first suggestion please read my comment in @ethicallogics answer. About the second one, I'd like to avoid it if possible :)

Comment: @EduardoBrites: The problem you have with the first suggestion is that WPF will never call your getter for IsValid unless it thinks it has changed. The only time it will think it has changed is when you call NotifyPropertyChanged("IsValid"). So you need to do the second option. You can't call NotifyPropertyChanged in GetValidationError because GetValidationError only gets called from the IsValid getter and the IsValid getter only gets called (apart from the first initial call - which causes your SO) when NotifyPropertyChanged is called. See the problem?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I was hoping that someone would think in a more elegant solution though...

Answer (score 0):

```
        private bool _isValid;
    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(GetValidationError())
            return _isValid;
        }
        set
        {
            _isValid = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsValid");
        }
    }

    public string GetValidationError()
    {
        string error = null;

        if (ValidatedProperties != null)
        {
            foreach (string s in ValidatedProperties)
            {
                error = GetValidationError(s);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(error))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        IsValid=string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(error);
        return error;
    }
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: I already tried that, but as the setter is never used _isValid is always false...

Comment: I have updated the answer try it this way. I hope this will help.

Comment: I also get a StackOverflowException.

Comment: It is because somewhere your Validation logic  calls the IsValid property and hence it goes into infinite loop.Can you show your GetValidationError(s) method code

Comment: @EduardoBrites: As I said in the comment on my answer, it's because WPF won't get IsValid again *unless* you call NotifyPropertyChanged("IsValid"). And the only time you do that is when IsValid's getter is called!